# WinError -2147023673 solution?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the services of a bluetooth device. I can see my device by scanning, but I can't take any kind of data from it. I was using bleak.

That's the error it gives.

```
yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
pythonapi.PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr(error_code)
OSError: [WinError -2147023673] The operation was canceled by the user
```

And that's my code.

```
import asyncio 
from bleak import BleakClient

async def main():
    address = "D4:22:CD:00:03:9B"
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        svcs = await client.get_services()
        print("Services:")
        company = svcs.get_characteristic("15170x0886-4947-11E9-8646-D663BD873D93")
        print(company)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I could not find any solutions. Thanks in advance.